# unfortunately app has stopped - java.lang.runtimeexception your content must have a listview whose id attribute is android.r.id.list

Tags: java, android

I still newbie in Android Programming, and i success build the project but cant open in emulator (unfortunately app has stop). so I need your HELP, Please..!!

Here my logcat

```
11-11 06:10:57.871: E/AndroidRuntime(1684): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-11 06:10:57.871: E/AndroidRuntime(1684): Process: id.co.kendaricall, PID: 1684
11-11 06:10:57.871: E/AndroidRuntime(1684): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{id.co.kendaricall/id.co.kendaricall.KategoriActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
11-11 06:10:57.871: E/AndroidRuntime(1684):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
11-11 06:10:57.871: E/AndroidRuntime(1684):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
11-11 06:10:57.871: E/AndroidRuntime(1684):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
11-11 06:10:57.871: E/AndroidRuntime(1684):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
11-11 06:10:57.871: E/AndroidRuntime(1684):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-11 06:10:57.871: E/AndroidRuntime(1684):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
11-11 06:10:57.871: E/AndroidRuntime(1684):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
11-11 06:10:57.871: E/AndroidRuntime(1684):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-11 06:10:57.871: E/AndroidRuntime(1684):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-11 06:10:57.871: E/AndroidRuntime(1684):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
11-11 06:10:57.871: E/AndroidRuntime(1684):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
11-11 06:10:57.871: E/AndroidRuntime(1684):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-11 06:10:57.871: E/AndroidRuntime(1684): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
11-11 06:10:57.871: E/AndroidRuntime(1684):     at android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:243)
11-11 06:10:57.871: E/AndroidRuntime(1684):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:293)
11-11 06:10:57.871: E/AndroidRuntime(1684):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
11-11 06:10:57.871: E/AndroidRuntime(1684):     at id.co.kendaricall.KategoriActivity.onCreate(KategoriActivity.java:64)
11-11 06:10:57.871: E/AndroidRuntime(1684):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
11-11 06:10:57.871: E/AndroidRuntime(1684):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
11-11 06:10:57.871: E/AndroidRuntime(1684):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
11-11 06:10:57.871: E/AndroidRuntime(1684):     ... 11 more
```

This is my AndroidManifest.xml File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="id.co.kendaricall"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/KendariCallTheme">
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" 
                      android:required="false" />

    <activity android:name="id.co.kendaricall.KategoriActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
        <activity android:name="id.co.kendaricall.KontakDetailActivity" />
        <activity android:name="id.co.kendaricall.SettingActivity" />
        <activity android:name="id.co.kendaricall.TemplateActivity" />
        <activity android:name="id.co.kendaricall.KontakListActivity" />
        <activity android:name="id.co.kendaricall.PencarianActivity" />
        <activity android:name="id.co.kendaricall.KontakFavoritActivity" />
</application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEDGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

</manifest>
```

And Here My KategoriActivity.java file

```
package id.co.kendaricall;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.GridView;
import java.io.IOException;

public class KategoriActivity extends TemplateActivity {
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    /* renamed from: id.co.kendaricall.KategoriActivity.1 */
    class C00811 extends Handler {
        C00811() {
        }

        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            KategoriActivity.this.progressDialog.dismiss();
            KategoriActivity.this.myData.openDataBase();
            KategoriActivity.this.showKategoriList();
            KategoriActivity.this.pilihLokasiDialog(KategoriActivity.this.findViewById(C0089R.id.button_location));
        }
    }

    /* renamed from: id.co.kendaricall.KategoriActivity.2 */
    class C00822 extends Thread {
        private final /* synthetic */ Handler val$handler;

        C00822(Handler handler) {
            this.val$handler = handler;
        }

        public void run() {
            try {
                KategoriActivity.this.myData.createDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            this.val$handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        }
    }

    /* renamed from: id.co.kendaricall.KategoriActivity.3 */
    class C00833 implements OnItemClickListener {
        private final /* synthetic */ AdapterKategori val$adapter;

        C00833(AdapterKategori adapterKategori) {
            this.val$adapter = adapterKategori;
        }

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View v, int position, long id) {
            KategoriActivity.this.showKontakActivity(this.val$adapter.getItemId(position));
        }
    }

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(C0089R.layout.kategorigrid);
        headerSetup();
        setNavigation(HOME, "Kategori");
        getInitialData();
    }

    public void showKontakActivity(long itemId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
        setKotaLokasi();
    }

    private void getInitialData() {
        if (!this.myData.checkDataBase() || this.myData.isUpgrade()) {
            this.progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Loading ...");
            new C00822(new C00811()).start();
            return;
        }
        showKategoriList();
        setKotaLokasi();
        Log.i("KategoryActivity", "set kota lokasi");
    }

    public void showKategoriList() {
        GridView grid = (GridView) findViewById(C0089R.id.gridviewKategori);
        AdapterKategori adapter = new AdapterKategori(this);
        grid.setAdapter(adapter);
        grid.setOnItemClickListener(new C00833(adapter));
    }

    public void showKontakActivity(String idKategori) {
        Intent go = new Intent(this, KontakListActivity.class);
        go.putExtra("idKategori", idKategori);
        startActivity(go);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can we see contents of your layout?

Comment: The problem seems to be in your KategoriListActivity. Can you show the code of that activity ?>

Comment: *KontactListActivity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try, rename the `android:id` of your ListView like this (in your kategorigrid layout file):

```
<ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

Instead `android:id="@+id/list"` paste this: `android:id="@android+id/list"`

**UPDATE**

Something wrong with your id in GridView: `android:id="@id/gridviewKategori"` must be `android:id="@+id/gridviewKategori"`. You missed `+` symbol

Comment: Thanks bro...!! but i still doesnt work.. can u help me from this CatLog error :

Comment: 11-12 03:14:15.821: E/AndroidRuntime(1730): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{id.co.kendaricall/id.co.kendaricall.KategoriActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

Answer (score 1):

Set your GridView id with a plus sign as :

```
android:id="@+id/gridviewKategori"
```

and access as

```
gridview gv = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridviewkategori);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but it still doesnt work. plz check my logcat

Comment: 11-12 03:14:15.821: E/AndroidRuntime(1730): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{id.co.kendaricall/id.co.kendaricall.KategoriActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

Answer (score 0):

Here is my kategorigrid.xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:background="@color/background_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:id="@id/layout_header_container" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <GridView
        android:id="@id/gridviewKategori"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:cacheColorHint="@color/transparent"
        android:columnWidth="128.0dip"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="@dimen/padding_medium"
        android:listSelector="@color/transparent"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="@dimen/padding_medium" >
    </GridView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my KontakListActivity.java:

```
package id.co.kendaricall;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class KontakListActivity extends TemplateActivity {
    public static String ALAMAT_KONTAK;
    public static String ID_KONTAK;
    public static String KATEGORI_KONTAK;
    public static String NAMA_KONTAK;
    private String idKategori;

    static {
        ID_KONTAK = "id_kontak";
        NAMA_KONTAK = "nama_kontak";
        ALAMAT_KONTAK = "alamat_kontak";
        KATEGORI_KONTAK = "kategori_kontak";
    }

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.kontaklist);
        headerSetup();
        this.idKategori = getIntent().getExtras().getString("idKategori");
        showKontakList(this.idKategori);
    }

    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setNavigation(KATEGORI, this.myData.getKategoriById(this.idKategori));
        setKotaLokasi();
    }

    public void showKontakList(String idKategori) {
        Cursor myCursor = this.myData.getKontakByKotaAndKategori(idKategori);
        ArrayList<Kontak> myList = new ArrayList<Kontak>();
        myCursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!myCursor.isAfterLast()) {
            Kontak kontak = new Kontak();
            kontak.setId(myCursor.getString(myCursor.getColumnIndex("_id")));
            kontak.setNama(myCursor.getString(myCursor.getColumnIndex("nama")));
            kontak.setAlamat(myCursor.getString(myCursor.getColumnIndex("alamat")));
            kontak.setKawasan(myCursor.getString(myCursor.getColumnIndex("kawasan")));
            kontak.setTelepon(myCursor.getString(myCursor.getColumnIndex("nomor")));
            myList.add(kontak);
            myCursor.moveToNext();
        }
        setListAdapter(new AdapterKontakList(this, myList, this.myData.getKategoriById(this.idKategori)));
    }
}
```

Please check.